# How To Insert a Link in a HTML Document At Runtime?

Tags: delphi

After a lot of searching for createElement and insertAdjacentHTML on the web I came up with this code.  When the code is executed the link is not inserted into the HTML.  The link is a to a local file.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var
  HTMLDocument2Ifc: IHTMLDocument2;
  iLinkString: string;
  iTopicString: string;
  iLink: IHTMLElement;
begin
  FormInsertLink := TFormInsertLink.Create( Self );
  try
    if FormInsertLink.ShowModal = mrOk then
    begin
      // <A HREF="file://..\html\author.htm">Author</A>
      HTMLDocument2Ifc := TopicWebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
      iLinkString := FormInsertLink.EditLink1.Text; // file://..\html\author.htm
      iTopicString := FormInsertLink.EditTopic1.Text; // Author
      iLink := HTMLDocument2Ifc.createElement('a');
      iLink.InnerText := iLinkString;
      iLink.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', '<A HREF="' + iLinkString + '">' + iTopicString + '</A>');
    end;
  finally
    FormInsertLink.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: file:// looks for a local file. You probably want http:// instead?

Comment: The link is a to a local file not a http address.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not actually adding the new link to the DOM tree, that is why it does not appear in the HTML document. You are calling `insertAdjacentHTML()` on the new `IHTMLElement` when you need to call it on another `IHTMLElement` that is already present in the document instead, eg:

```
var 
  iDoc: IHTMLDocument2; 
  iElement: IHTMLElement; 
begin 
  FormInsertLink := TFormInsertLink.Create( Self ); 
  try 
    if FormInsertLink.ShowModal = mrOk then 
    begin 
      iDoc := TopicWebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2; 
      iElement := iDoc.all('some existing element'); 
      iElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', '<A HREF="' + FormInsertLink.EditLink1.Text + '">' + FormInsertLink.EditTopic1.Text + '</A>'); 
    end; 
  finally 
    FormInsertLink.Free; 
  end;
```

Or, use the `appendChild()` method instead:

```
var 
  iDoc: IHTMLDocument2; 
  iLink: IHTMLAnchorElement; 
begin 
  FormInsertLink := TFormInsertLink.Create( Self ); 
  try 
    if FormInsertLink.ShowModal = mrOk then 
    begin 
      iDoc := TopicWebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2; 
      iLink := iDoc.createElement('A') as IHTMLAnchorElement; 
      iLink.href := FormInsertLink.EditLink1.Text;
      (iLink as IHTMLElement).innerText := FormInsertLink.EditTopic1.Text;
      (iDoc.body as IHTMLDOMNode).appendChild(iLink as IHTMLDOMNode); 
    end; 
  finally 
    FormInsertLink.Free; 
  end;
```

**Update**: to wrap selected text with an `<a>` tag:

```
var 
  iDoc: IHTMLDocument2; 
  iSelection: IHTMLSelectionObject;
  iRange: IHTMLTxtRange;
begin 
  FormInsertLink := TFormInsertLink.Create( Self ); 
  try 
    if FormInsertLink.ShowModal = mrOk then 
    begin 
      iDoc := TopicWebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2; 
      iSelection := iDoc.selection as IHTMLSelectionObject;
      iRange := iSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange; 
      iRange.pasteHTML('<a href="' + FormInsertLink.EditLink1.Text + '">' + FormInsertLink.EditTopic1.Text + '</a>');
      // or:
      // iRange.pasteHTML('<a href="' + FormInsertLink.EditLink1.Text + '">' + iRange.text + '</a>');
    end; 
  finally 
    FormInsertLink.Free; 
  end;
```

**Update**: to change selected text into an `<a>` tag using `IHTMLDocument2.execCommand()`:

```
FormInsertLink := TFormInsertLink.Create( Self ); 
try 
  if FormInsertLink.ShowModal = mrOk then 
  begin 
    (TopicWebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).execCommand('CreateLink', False, FormInsertLink.EditLink1.Text);
  end; 
finally 
  FormInsertLink.Free; 
end;
```

Comment: @Remy,
iLink: IHTMLAnchorElement does not have an innerText property and iDoc: IHTMLDocument2 does not have a appendChild property with Delphi 2010?  Also... if iLink := iDoc.createElement('A') as IHTMLAnchorElement is used should 'A' be used each time a link is created?

Comment: @Toby... yes true... but iLink was an IHTMLElement not a IHTMLAnchorElement.

Comment: Query the `IHTMLAnchorElement` object for its `IHTMLElement` interface, then you can set the `IHTMLElement.InnerText` property.  The `IHTMLDocument2.body` property returns an `IHTMLElement`, query it for its `IHTMLDOMNode` interface, then you can call the `IHTMLDOMNode.appendChild()` method. The `IHTMLDocument2.createElement()` method expects an HTML tag name as input.  HTML anchors use the `<A>` tag, so you use `'A'` to create an `IHTMLAnchorElement` instance.

Comment: @Remy,  First let me thank-you for your help.  The 2nd method compiles but does not create the lnk so I tested the 1st method.    The first method will not compile because iDoc.all does not have any parameters.  Finally, how would you get the existing element?  The element is <body> I think, but the selection is a word in the body to create the link around.  But maybe I am confused because I have tried to get this to work for 2 days now.

Comment: @Bill: `iDoc.all` returns an `IDispatch` in Delphi. Query that for its `IHTMLElementCollection` interface, then call the `IHTMLElementCollection.item()` method. Regarding *where* to insert the link, what are you actually trying to accomplish in the first place? Your original question does not make that clear. There are different ways to insert new elements relative to other elements or the document itself.

Comment: I tested the 2nd approach, it works for me.  I see the new link appear in the document.  But now you say you are trying to wrap selected text with an `<a>` tag.  That is a COMPLETELY different issue than you have been asking for.  For that, use the `IHTMLDocument2.selection` property to retreive an `IHTMLSelectionObject`, then call the `IHTMLSelectionObject.createRange()` method to get an `IHTMLTxtRange`, read the `IHTMLTxtRange.text` property to get the selected text, then call the `IHTMLTxtRange.pasteHTML()` method to replace the selected text with your `<A ...>` HTML text.  Works for me.

Comment: @Remy I am just trying to replace HTMLDocument2Ifc.execCommand( 'CreateLink', True, 0 ) with HTMLDocument2Ifc.execCommand( 'CreateLink', False, 0 ) then use my own dialog to set the link.  So what I am trying to do is to select a word in the document in WebBrowser, then when a insertlink button is pressed by the user, a link is created for the selected word...  exactly like HTMLDocument2Ifc.execCommand( 'CreateLink', True, 0 ) does but with no GUI interface supplied by WebBrowser.

Comment: @Bill, you should have said that in the first place instead of wasting my time putting together answers for you that are not relevant to your actual situation.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @Remy,  I have managed to get it to work as I explained using the info you provided in IHTMLTxtRange.text property to get the selected text, then calling the IHTMLTxtRange.pasteHTML() method.  Thank-you very much for your assistance.  After your last post it was easy to do.